# Organizing optional imports in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm working on a Python 3 project which involves writing data. Now, I want the user to be able to choose a format for the data to be written in – pickle, SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc.
Well, pickle and sqlite support is built into Python, so no worries there. Other stuff needs importing other modules, though.

The project, without going into unnecessary detail, consists of the following:
A class `ProjectClass` which has `read`, `write`, etc. methods, which write data to columns, create new columns etc. So the user chooses the backend when creating an object of the `ProjectClass` type:

```
from project import ProjectClass
instance = ProjectClass(backend='MySQL')
instance.write(column_name='column1', data=some_data)
```

And the backend handles all the database stuff (so the `ProjectClass` is database-agnostic).
The `read`, `write` and other methods call functions from `backends.py`, and the function they call depends on the backend type passed to the `ProjectClass` instance when creating it.

Now, I can't fully understand how to:

1. not have the user install every package for every backend (since, hopefully, the project will grow and support more and more DB backends)
2. check if the necessary package is installed (`psycopg2` for PostgreSQL, etc)

Should I split the backends into separate files for each database types, and when the user creates a `ProjectType` instance, it tries to import the necessary file (`postgresqlbackend.py` for PostgreSQL, `mysqlbackend.py` for MySQL, etc.) and see if the import fails (due to absence of packages that are imported in the `<backendname>backend.py` file)?

Comment: Your suggested solution sounds like a good idea, yes.  I can't tell if you're asking for more than a yes-or-no answer there.

Comment: It's perhaps a yes/no question, but I'm not entirely sure if my solution is the best one possible, so I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I split the backends into separate files for each database
>   types, and when the user creates a ProjectType instance, it tries to
>   import the necessary file

This sounds like a good idea. Don't forget however that you can also import a module anywhere (it can be inside a function - it doesn't need to be at the top of file). Then you can surround this `import` statement with a `try/except` and warn the user beforehand.

```
try:
    import non_existant_module
except ImportError as e:
    print e.message # prints "No module named non_existant_module"
```

The best approach IMO is to print this error when your program first starts after loading the runtime config specifying which module/database type will be used. That way the user is instantly notified.

Comment: You can use `try`/`except` outside a function too.